# reformat unstructured text into single line after removing punctuation

Tags: python, string

I have an unstructured text which I want to convert into 1 line and remove all the punctuation marks.

For the punctuation marks i used the following solution [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

---

How can i reformat the unstructured text into 1 line by using python?

---

Example 1:

> The Bourne Identity is a 2002 spy film loosely based on Robert
>   Ludlum's novel of the same name. It stars Matt Damon as Jason Bourne,
>   an amnesiac attempting to discover his true identity amidst a
>   clandestine conspiracy within the Central Intelligence Agency (CIA) to
>   track him down and arrest or kill him for inexplicably failing to
>   carry out an officially unsanctioned assassination and then failing to
>   report back in afterwards. Along the way he teams up with Marie,
>   played by Franka Potente, who assists him on the initial part of his
>   journey to learn about his past and regain his memories. The film also
>   stars Chris Cooper as Alexander Conklin, Clive Owen as The Professor,
>   Brian Cox as Ward Abbott, and Julia Stiles as Nicky Parsons.
>
> The film was directed by Doug Liman and adapted for the screen by Tony
>   Gilroy and William Blake Herron from the novel of the same name
>   written by Robert Ludlum, who also produced the film alongside Frank
>   Marshall. Universal Studios released the film to theaters in the
>   United States on June 14, 2002 and it received a positive critical and
>   public reaction. The film was followed by a 2004 sequel, The Bourne
>   Supremacy, and a third part released in 2007 entitled The Bourne
>   Ultimatum.
>
> Plot

---

Example 2:

> ```
> 12 (0) 0 4 (0)  38 (3) 0 3 (0) 0 1 (0)
> ```

---

Example 3:

> ```
> Franklin Township is one of the eighteen townships of Monroe County, Ohio,
> United States. The 2000 census found 453 people in the township, 367 of whom
> lived in the unincorporated portions of the township.
>
>  Geography
>
> Located in the western part of the county, it borders the following townships:
>
> The village of Stafford lies in southwestern Franklin Township.
>
>  Name and history
>
> It is one of twenty-one Franklin Townships statewide.
>
>  Government
>
> The township is governed by a three-member board of trustees, who are elected in
> November of odd-numbered years to a four-year term beginning on the following
> January 1. Two are elected in the year after the presidential election and one
> is elected in the year before it. There is also an elected township clerk, who
> serves a four-year term beginning on April 1 of the year after the election,
> which is held in November of the year before the presidential election.
> Vacancies in the clerkship or on the board of trustees are filled by the
> remaining trustees.
> ```

---

As you can see in the previous examples. The text have different formats. How can I turn every single text into 1 line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward - basically, other than the punctuation, you are now also looking to eliminate the line endings.

So, you can simply do:

```
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation +  "\n\t\r")
print ''.join(ch for ch in input_string if ch not in exclude)
```

> input_string = """The Bourne Identity is a 2002 spy film loosely based on Robert Ludlum's novel of the same name. It stars Matt Damon as Jason Bourne, an amnesiac attempting to discover his true identity amidst a clandestine conspiracy within the Central Intelligence Agency (CIA) to track him down and arrest or kill him for inexplicably failing to carry out an officially unsanctioned assassination and then failing to report back in afterwards. Along the way he teams up with Marie, played by Franka Potente, who assists him on the initial part of his journey to learn about his past and regain his memories. The film also stars Chris Cooper as Alexander Conklin, Clive Owen as The Professor, Brian Cox as Ward Abbott, and Julia Stiles as Nicky Parsons.
>
> The film was directed by Doug Liman and adapted for the screen by Tony Gilroy and William Blake Herron from the novel of the same name written by Robert Ludlum, who also produced the film alongside Frank Marshall. Universal Studios released the film to theaters in the United States on June 14, 2002 and it received a positive critical and public reaction. The film was followed by a 2004 sequel, The Bourne Supremacy, and a third part released in 2007 entitled The Bourne Ultimatum."""

```
>>> print ''.join(ch for ch in input_string if ch not in exclude)
The Bourne Identity is a 2002 spy film loosely based on Robert Ludlums novel of the same name It stars Matt Damon as Jason Bourne an amnesiac attempting to discover his true identity amidst a clandestine conspiracy within the Central Intelligence Agency CIA to track him down and arrest or kill him for inexplicably failing to carry out an officially unsanctioned assassination and then failing to report back in afterwards Along the way he teams up with Marie played by Franka Potente who assists him on the initial part of his journey to learn about his past and regain his memories The film also stars Chris Cooper as Alexander Conklin Clive Owen as The Professor Brian Cox as Ward Abbott and Julia Stiles as Nicky ParsonsThe film was directed by Doug Liman and adapted for the screen by Tony Gilroy and William Blake Herron from the novel of the same name written by Robert Ludlum who also produced the film alongside Frank Marshall Universal Studios released the film to theaters in the United States on June 14 2002 and it received a positive critical and public reaction The film was followed by a 2004 sequel The Bourne Supremacy and a third part released in 2007 entitled The Bourne Ultimatum
```

Comment: so you excluse all the "\n\t\r" and then u join all the other elements together in the string with a white space ' ' between them.

Comment: @HaniGoc No, I don't join them with a whitespace, I just remove the line ending characters. If you want to replace each of those with, you could do this in another join operation.